# Inverse normal cumulative distribution function conversion

Tags: java, c#

we used the Extreme Numerics library from Extreme Optimization (http://www.extremeoptimization.com) for our calculation kernel.

```
// portfolio risk is inverse normal cumulative distribution function
double risk = NormalDistribution.InverseDistributionFunction(
  _riskProbabilityLevel, 
  mean, 
  stdev);
```

The problem is now we are moving from C# to Java and I don't really know all that much about Java but have been tasked with re-writing this particular function.

I have values to test against:

```
RiskProbabilityLevel = 0.02
Mean                 = 0.06618
Standard Dev         = 0.057196166520267355

Risk                 = 0.051286461995869864
```

but in looking thru the various functions in `math3.distribution.NormalDistribution` libraries I can't find what might be equivalent.

Any direction or help would be appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the people who thought this was off topic, considering how there was really only one way to convert 'x' to 'y' I'm not sure how its way too broad.  Regardless, man saved my job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can use [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/NormalDistribution.html) library. It's called `apache commons.math3`. It's very popular. From the docs supplied by [http://www.extremeoptimization.com](http://www.extremeoptimization.com/Documentation/Reference/Extreme.Statistics.Distributions.NormalDistribution.DistributionFunction-2.aspx) I think you can use the following code:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution;

public class TestProbabilites {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double riskProbabilityLevel = 0.02D;
        double mean = 0.06618D;
        double standardDev = 0.057196166520267355D;
        double expectedRisk = 0.051286461995869864D;

        NormalDistribution distribution = new NormalDistribution(mean, standardDev);
        double outcomeRisk = distribution.inverseCumulativeProbability(riskProbabilityLevel);
    }
}
```

But you have to remember to add the `apache.commons.math3` library added to your project using `Maven` or `Gradle` or some other dependencies manager.

Hopes this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, life saver!